# Find best match for multiple substrings across multiple candidates

Tags: r, substring

I have the following sample data:

```
targets <- c("der", "das")
candidates <- c("sdassder", "sderf", "fongs")
```

**Desired Output:**

I would like to find `sdassder` as the Output since it includes the most Matches for `targets` (as substrings).

**What i tried:**

```
x <- sapply(targets, function(target) sapply(candidates, grep, pattern = target)) > 0
which.max(rowSums(x))
```

**Goal:**

As you can see, i found some dirty Code that technically yields the result, but i dont feel its a best practise.I hope this Question fits here otherwise i move to Code review.

I tried mapply, do.call, outer, but didnt manage to find a better Code.

**Edit:**

Adding another Option myself, after seeing the current answers.

Using pipes:

```
sapply(targets, grepl, candidates) %>% rowSums %>% which.max %>% candidates[.]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it a little, I think.

```r
matches <- sapply(targets, grepl, candidates)
matches
#        der   das
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE
```

And find the number of matches using `rowSums`:

```r
rowSums(matches)
# [1] 2 1 0
candidates[ which.max(rowSums(matches)) ]
# [1] "sdassder"
```

(Note that this last part does not really inform about ties.)

If you want to see the individual matches per-candidate, you can always apply the names manually, though this is only an aesthetic thing, adding very little to the work itself.

```r
rownames(matches) <- candidates
matches
#            der   das
# sdassder  TRUE  TRUE
# sderf     TRUE FALSE
# fongs    FALSE FALSE
rowSums(matches)
# sdassder    sderf    fongs 
#        2        1        0 
which.max(rowSums(matches))
# sdassder 
#        1        <------ this "1" indicates the index within the rowSums vector
names(which.max(rowSums(matches)))
# [1] "sdassder"
```

Answer (score 3):

One `stringr` option could be:

```
candidates[which.max(rowSums(outer(candidates, targets, str_detect)))]

[1] "sdassder"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could paste the `targets` together and create a pattern to match.

```
library(stringr)
str_c(targets, collapse = "|")
#[1] "der|das"
```

Use it in `str_count` to count the number of times pattern was matched.

```
str_count(candidates, str_c(targets, collapse = "|"))
#[1] 2 1 0
```

Get the index of maximum value and subset it from original `candidates`

```
candidates[which.max(str_count(candidates, str_c(targets, collapse = "|")))]
#[1] "sdassder"
```